# Sorting of Table using PHP

Tags: php, html, sorting, html-table

After typing the correct code, the sorting of the table did not appear at all. Please help me.  I did include my CSS style and PHP coding. Thank you!

below is the image of the current result:

[image: capture3]

this is my PHP coding:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="thead.css"/>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> 
    <script type ="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() 
            { 
                $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
            } 
        ); 
    </script>
</head> 
<body>  

    <?php

    if ($_SESSION ['role_id'] == 1) {   ?>
    <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

    <table border='1' width='78%' id='myTable' class='tablesorter'>
                    <thead>
                    <tr class= 'header'>
                        <th>  Booking ID  </th>
                        <th>  Staff ID     </th>
                        <th>   Asset ID    </th>
                        <th>  Start Date    </th>
                        <th>  End Date      </th>
                       <th>Collection Date </th>
                        <th> Actual Return Date </th>

                    </tr> 
                    </thead> 
                        <tbody>
         <?php 
                while ($fetchSelect = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $id = $fetchSelect['booking_id'];
                $staffid = $fetchSelect['user_id'];
                $assetid = $fetchSelect['asset_id'];
                $startdate = $fetchSelect['start_date'];
                $duedate = $fetchSelect['due_date'];
                $collectiondate = $fetchSelect['collection_date'];
                $returndate = $fetchSelect['return_date'];
                ?>

                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $staffid; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $assetid; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $startdate; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $duedate; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $collectiondate; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $returndate; ?></td>


    <?php
         } ?>
            </tbody>
            </table>
    <?php
    }else{ 
        exit;
    }
    </body>
    </html>
```

My CSS style:

```
    table.sortable thead {
        background-color:#eee;
        color:#666666;
        font-weight: bold;
        cursor: default;
    }

    table.sortable th:not(.sorttable_sorted):not(.sorttable_sorted_reverse):not(.sorttable_nosort):after { 
        content: " \25B4\25BE" 
    }
```

Comment: Use data tables for the purpose of showing tables. It provides multiple features like sorting pagination etc

Comment: why you are starting 2 table tag . just wondered    `<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

    <table border='1' width='78%' id='myTable' class='tablesorter'>`

Comment: There are two tables initialised, keep only one. Also, you forgot to close `</tr>` in the loop.

Comment: http://tablesorter.com/docs/ this document example is very clear

Comment: Please check my JSFiddle for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/983fwq38/

Comment: As far as i can remember I had some issues making sorting work when I had the "<tbody>".

Comment: Thank you for all your help! My code is able to work!(: Much appreciated. Have a great day

Answer (score 0):

For sorting I use this:

In my table header i just add

> `<th onclick='sortTable(this)'>[HeaderTextHere]</th>`

Javascipt code:

```
var tableId;
// Gets the table by its id
var $ = function( id ) {  return document.getElementById( id ); },
  $$ = function( query , base ) {
    return ( base||document).querySelectorAll( query );
  },
  table = $(tableId),
  rows = [], 
  cellClassArray = [];
//populates the row array and the class array
function getSortable(columnClicked){
  var trows = document.getElementById(tableId).rows , //the unmodified rows
    rows =[], //the rowdata from start to end '<tr>...</tr>'
    cells =[], //innerHTML of selected cell
    cellClassArray =[]; //class names from the cells

  for( var i = 1; i< trows.length; i++ ) {
    //contains the class of the working cell
    var cellClass = trows[i].cells[0].className;
    //adding the cell values to the cell array
    cells.push(trows[i].cells[columnClicked].innerHTML);
    //if a new cellclass comes up then add it to the cellClassArray 
    //later I should also make an array for rowClass so this script also would work on tables where the class is set rowbased
    if(cellClassArray.indexOf(cellClass) == -1)
      cellClassArray.push(cellClass);
    //going through all the cells and deleting all class data
    for(z = 0; trows[i].cells.length > z; z++)
      trows[i].cells[z].className = '';
    //adding the working row to the rows array
    rows.push( trows[i] );
  }
  //creating and returning the multidim array, could maybe be improved
  var rowsAndClassArrays = [rows, cellClassArray, cells];
  return rowsAndClassArrays;
}

//Deletes and re-inserting the table
function updateRows( rows, tableId, cellClassArray) {
  //getting the table element
  var table = document.getElementById(tableId);
  //Deleting all rows in the table(except the header)
  while (table.rows.length > 1) {
    table.removeChild(table.lastChild);
  }

  //z shoud be changed to an int later on, to make it possible to have more than 2 row classes
  var z = true;
  //Re-inserting the rows
  for ( var i =0; i< rows.length ;i++ ){
    //Seemed better to put it into a var at time of writing
    var workRow = rows[i];
    //when changing z to int remember to also change this if to a switch
    //Giving the cells a classname if the had any
    if(z) {
      for(q = 0; rows[i].cells.length > q; q++)
        workRow.cells[q].className = cellClassArray[0];
    }
    else {
      for(q = 0; rows[i].cells.length > q; q++)
        workRow.cells[q].className = cellClassArray[1];
    }
    z = !z;
    //appending the rows to the table
    table.appendChild( workRow );
  }
}

function sortAlphabetically( el, tableId, columnClicked){
  //el i a bool for sort direction
  el.sort = ! el.sort;
  //array contaning row clases, rows, and value of the rows
  var rowsAndClassArray = getSortable(columnClicked),
  rows = [];
  //creating multidim array to make sorting easy
  for(var i = 0; i < rowsAndClassArray[0].length; i++) {
    rows[i] = [rowsAndClassArray[0][i], rowsAndClassArray[2][i]];  //[0] is the raw row data, [1] is the innerHTML of the selected column
  }
  //Sorting the rows 
  rows.sort(
    function(a, b) {
      if (a[1] === b[1]) {
        return 0;
      }
      else {
          return (el.sort) ? ((a[1] < b[1]) ? -1 : 1) : ((a[1] > b[1]) ? -1 : 1);
      }
    }
  );
  var cleanRows = []; // after sorting we dont need the column values anymore 
  for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  cleanRows.push(rows[i][0]);
  }
  cellClassArray = rowsAndClassArray[1];
  //updateRows is deleting all rows and inserting rows in the new order
  updateRows(cleanRows, tableId, cellClassArray);
}

function sortTable(th) {
    var columnNumber = th.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.rows[0].cells.length;
    //Debugging code saved for latter use 
    //console.log(th.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.rows[0].cells.length);
    //Caluculates what colum that have been clicked
    var columnClicked;
    for(i = 0; i < columnNumber; i++) {
      if(th == th.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.rows[0].cells[i]) {
        columnClicked = i;
        break;
      }
    }
    //geting the tabel id
    tableId = th.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id;
    //sorting rows based on the clicked column and updates the table on the page
    sortAlphabetically(th, tableId, columnClicked);
}
```

It is not perfect and have some flaws, but hope that it can help you move forward.

Comment: tablesorter is a plugin why you want to develop custom code here

Comment: I cant remember why, but the tablesorter gave me some issues/was not playing nice, when i was playing with sorting, and therefore i made custom code instead.

Comment: Thank you so much(: I really appreciate your help lots. My code is able to work already! Have a great day(:

Answer (score 0):

Some cases may cause the error

1. You didn't closed the php closing tag

   `<?php
    }else{ 
       exit;
    }
    ?>
    // '?>' is missed
    </body>
    </html>`
2. $_SESSION ['role_id'] doesn't contain 1(may be).
3. If both of above cases is not the soln try the example i tried [link](http://codepad.org/ORqz8qpP)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort table using php only add order by  ACS or DESC in your Query as the end of query. It will show sorting as you want.

no need any sorting table... focus on ur query only.

e. g.   select * from student order by marks desc;

it will showing highest mark first in sorting records.

Is it ok for you.. or you want sorting with table sort.